# How to write a custom function of m-order difference?

Tags: interpolation

In the text, the formula of calculating `m`-order difference with `m + 1` nodes is as follows:

$$f\left[x_{k}, x_{k+1}\right]=\frac{f\left(x_{k+1}\right)-f\left(x_{k}\right)}{x_{k+1}-x_{k}}$$
$$f\left[x_{k}, x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_{k+m}\right]=\frac{f\left[x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_{k+m}\right]-f\left[x_{k}, \cdots, x_{k+m-1}\right]}{x_{k+m}-x_{k}}$$

The Newton interpolation formula with `n+1` nodes can be obtained by using the above formula:

$$\begin{aligned}
N_{n}(x)=& f\left(x_{0}\right)+f\left[x_{0}, x_{1}\right]\left(x-x_{0}\right)+f\left[x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}\right]\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{1}\right)+\cdots \\
&+f\left[x_{0}, x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}\right]\left(x-x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{1}\right) \cdots\left(x-x_{n-1}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

But the built-in function `DifferenceQuotient` can only calculate high-order difference for equal step `h`:

```
DifferenceQuotient[f[x], {x, 3, h}]
```

What can I do to write an ingenious `m`-order difference function to calculate Newton's interpolation polynomials?

**Update:** I tried to write a custom function `Newton` to solve this problem, I hope I can get other more ingenious methods $\color{Gray}  {\text{(武汉 岩石 数值分析-2007-2)}} $:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
f[{x_, y_}] := (f[y] - f[x])/(y - x)
f[x_List] := (f[Drop[x, {Length[x] - 1}]] - 
    f[Drop[x, {Length[x]}]])/(x[[Length[x]]] - x[[Length[x] - 1]])
ω[n_, s_] := Product[(s - xx[[i]]), {i, 1, n}]
xx = {0., 1., 2., 3.};
y = {2., 3., 0., -1.};
Evaluate[(f /@ xx)] = y;
Newton[n_?(# > 0 && IntegerQ[#] &), s_ : x] := 
 f[xx[[1]]] + 
  Sum[f[Table[xx[[i]], {i, 1, m + 1}]]*ω[m, s], {m, 1, n}]

Newton[3, x] // Expand
```

**Note:** These definitions used are from page 99 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006619745&d=E56F21862F9CC8711CE225504A71AE30&fenlei=13011601).

[image]

Or use the definition on page 5 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006641172&d=CB6E1ED34FB8B2B0879DD74D4A4AA569&fenlei=130116):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. I have updated the question.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong, please double check it.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I have added some necessary information. Equation `(3.3)` and equation `(3.3')` are equivalent.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. The results of `Newton[4, x] // Expand` and `InterpolatingPolynomial[{xx, y}\[Transpose], x] // Expand` are the same. I'll check it again.

Comment: I see, I've made a mistake in testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newton[{X_, Y_}, x_] := 
 Module[{f, asso = X -> Y // Thread // Association}, 
  f@{a_, b___, c_} := f@{a, b, c} = (f@{b, c} - f@{a, b})/(c - a);
  f@{a_} := asso@a;
  Sum[f@# Times @@ (x - Most@#) &@X[[;; i]], {i, Length@X}]]    

xx = {0., 1., 2., 3., 5};
y = {2., 3., 0., -1., -3};
newton[{xx, y}, x] // Expand
(* 2. + 6.5 x - 7.75 x^2 + 2.5 x^3 - 0.25 x^4 *)
```