# How can I fix my Simpson's rule integration code?

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction, pattern-matching, homework, arguments

I was tasked with writing a function on Mathematica similar to `NIntegrate`, but that uses the [Composite Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson%27s_rule) as its method for doing the calculation. The function should take as arguments, the function to be integrated (aka the integrand), the integration variable (as well as its upper and lower limits) and how many equally spaced subdivisions it should use to do the calculation.

The function is only required to integrate in regards to one variable; however, if presented with a multivariable function it must be able to integrate over only one designed variable and ignore the others.

I was able to handle that following [another question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/passing-a-function-as-an-argument-of-another-function?newreg=4e6532c2a8164d059b8fe0a82a42f0ed). And came up with the following code:

```
    SetAttributes[SimpsonIntegral, HoldAll]
    SimpsonIntegral[f_[a___, var_, b___], {var_, xmin_, xmax_}, steps_] :=
    (xmax - xmin)/(3 steps) Sum[f[a, xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y - 2), b] + 
    4*f[a, xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y - 1), b] + 
    f[a, xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y), b], {y, 1, steps/2}];
```

It worked perfectly fine with single variable functions (like `Sin[x]`) and even multivariable functions (like `BesselJ[n,z]`). However, it fails when the input function takes an expression as its argument. For example:

```
SimpsonIntegral[Sin[x - 1], {x, 0, 1}, 6]
```

would simply return unevaluated:

> SimpsonIntegral[Sin[x - 1], {x, 0, 1}, 6]

instead of the various terms of the sum.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So, `SimpsonIntegral[2, {x, 0, 1}, 4]` is not expected to evaluate?

Comment: It is not clear what role play `a, b` in your function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend more practical for numerical calculations next definition:

```
SetAttributes[SimpsonIntegral, HoldAll]
SimpsonIntegral[f_, x_, xmin_, xmax_, 
   steps_] := (xmax - xmin)/(3 steps) (Sum[
      f /. {x -> xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y - 2)}, {y, 1, 
       steps/2}] + 
     4*Sum[f /. {x -> xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y - 1)}, {y, 1, 
        steps/2}] + 
     Sum[f /. {x -> xmin + (xmax - xmin)/steps (2*y)}, {y, 1, 
       steps/2}]);
```

Then we have for `BesselJ[]`

```
SimpsonIntegral[BesselJ[2, 3 x + 2], x, 0, 1, 8] // N

Out[]= 0.366069
```

Let compare with `NIntegrate`

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[2, 3 x + 2], {x, 0, 1}]

Out[]= 0.3660498384281397
```

As expected the error for unit interval is bounded as $\frac{h^4}{180}max|f^{(4)}(x)|$, so with `h=1/8` it gives $1.35634\times 10^{-6}\times 20.496=2.78 \times 10^{-5} $, and we have from above error of $1.9\times 
10^{-5}$. From the other side we can calculate exactly

```
i = Integrate[BesselJ[2, 3 x + 2], {x, 0, 1}]

Out[]= 1/72 (125 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2}, {5/2, 3}, -(25/4)] - 
   8 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2}, {5/2, 3}, -1])
```

Then we can numerically compute

```
i // N

0.36604983842813943
```

Let compare results given by `NIntegrate` and `Integrate` to support error bound verification. So in this case `NIntegrate` really working with `MachinePrecision`. To calculate $max|f^{(4)}(x)|$ we use

```
FindMaximum[D[BesselJ[2, 3 x + 1], {x, 4}], {x, .8}]

Out[]= {20.496, {x -> 0.752259}}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I wonder if you can use MMA to get the truncation error  $\frac{h^4}{180}max|f^{(4)}(x)|$.

Comment: Do you mean formula or numerical result? For numerical result I gave some update.

Comment: If you can, I hope you can write a function as general as possible to solve the representation of [truncation error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230309/how-to-calculate-the-expression-of-error-truncation-function) in numerical analysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The function `MyPlot`, which is the model for your implementation, is specialized to a certain argument pattern and won't evaluate when given `Sin[x + 1]` as its argument, either. It requires the variable of interest to appear in its argument sequence "naked". It can not be a factor in an expression. The simple solution is to define a new function which provides the required isolation. Like so:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x - 1]
SimpsonIntegral[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 6]
```

> ```
> 1/18 (-4 Sin[1/6] - 2 Sin[1/3] - 4 Sin[1/2] - 2 Sin[2/3] - 4 Sin[5/6] - Sin[1])
> ```

If that isn't an acceptable solution, then you need find a different approach.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this should work!

Comment: @CarlosM. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: @m_goldberg I am clicking (+1) for you solution but the definition of `SimpsonIntegral[]` should be reconsidered.

Comment: @AlexTrounev. I am in full agreement with you.